# Automatically transform all variables in a class to "self" variables

Tags: python, class, self, manim

My code (minimal example) looks like this:

```py
class Hello:
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    def __init__(self):
        self.d= 4
```

and I am searching for a function like `set_all_vars_to_self_vars()` which I can call in the class `Hello`, so that the `Hello` class becomes equvilent to:

```py
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 4
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
```

Is there some functionality that does that?

The rich example looks like this:

```py
from manim import *

class Scene1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot = Dot()
        circ= Circle()
        self.add(dot,circ)
        self.set_variables_as_attrs(dot)  # at the moment, variables have to be added manually
        return self

class Scene2(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        sc1 = Scene1.construct(self)
        dot2= Dot().next_to(sc1.dot)
        self.play(ShowCreation(dot2))
```

Comment: Use an IDE. Pycharm should be able to do that.

Comment: When you just have numbers like 1,2,3,4 you don’t need anything different to your first snippet.

Comment: My example is a minimal example for a more complicated case. I don't want my code to look like example 2, but only to behave like it. The reason: There are about 300 lines where I use a,b,c and I don't want to use every time `self. ` for reasons of readability

Comment: Perhaps you could change your minimal example to include more realistic variable types. At the moment you don’t need code like your second snippet.

Comment: Ok, it's updated

Comment: I don't understand how the code in your "rich example" relates to your question. What is it you want to change in your code?

Comment: Well, I don’t see the connection. When you have dot = Dot(), did you mean to do: self.dot = Dot() ?

Comment: I want self.dot= dot and self.circ= circ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables you define outside the `__init__` are **not at all comparable** with these you declare inside the `__init__`. The first ones belong to the `Class`, the second ones belong the the `Object`.

Thus, if you want `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` to change with each instance of `Hello()`, you should not declare them outside the scope of the `__init__()`. They simply do not have the same meaning.

However, if it is what you want to do, here is how to do this:

```
class Hello:
    a = 4
    b = 4
    c = 4

    def __init__(self):
        d = 4
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not callable(attr) and not attr.startwith('__'):
                self.__dict__.setdefault(attr, Hello.__dict__.get(attr))
```

Then, with `H = Hello()` you will have, for example, `H.a = Hello.a`.
More generally, you will have a copy of each variable of the `Class` for each `Instance` of your `Class`.

Is this want you wanted?